# Add class on Scroll event in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, events, onscroll

this is my react js code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "../images/logo.png";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";
import $ from "jquery";
import "./Navbar.css";

function Navbar() {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      const scrollValue = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      if (scrollValue > 100) {
        const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar_menu_heade");
        navbar.classList.add("show");
      } else {
        const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar_menu_heade");
        navbar.classList.remove("show");
      }
    });
  });
  function animation() {
    var tabsNewAnim = $("#navbarSupportedContent ");
    var activeItemNewAnim = tabsNewAnim.find(" .active");
    var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = activeItemNewAnim.innerHeight();
    var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = activeItemNewAnim.innerWidth();
    var itemPosNewAnimTop = activeItemNewAnim.position();
    var itemPosNewAnimLeft = activeItemNewAnim.position();
    $(".hori-selector").css({
      top: itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px",
      left: itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
      height: activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
      width: activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px",
    });


$("#navbarSupportedContent").on("scroll", "li", function (e) {
  $("#navbarSupportedContent ul li ").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
  var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
  var itemPosNewAnimTop = $(this).position();
  var itemPosNewAnimLeft = $(this).position();
  $(".hori-selector").css({
    top: itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px",
    left: itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
    height: activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
    width: activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px",
  });
});}



useEffect(() => {
    animation();
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        animation();
      }, 500);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="navbar_menu_heade">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-mainbg">
        <Link to="home" offset={-80} className="navbar-brand navbar-logo">
            <img src={logo} alt="logo" className='logoimg' />
          </Link>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler shadow-none"
          onClick={function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
              animation();
            });
          }}
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <i className="fas fa-bars "></i>
        </button>

    <div className="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
        <div className="hori-selector">
          <div className="left"></div>
          <div className="right"></div>
        </div>
        <li className="nav-item active">
        <Link to="home" spy={true} offset={-80} className="nav-link">
          Home
        </Link>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link " spy={true} offset={-80} to="about">
            About
          </Link>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" spy={true} offset={-80} to="services">
            Services
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" spy={true} offset={-80} to="career">
            Career
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" spy={true} offset={-80} to="portfolio">
            Portfolio
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" spy={true} offset={-80} to="contact">
            Contact
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>


);}
export default Navbar;
```

In this code i have a navbar which has applied css which is following:

```
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: #fff; /* fallback for old browsers */
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar-logo {
  padding: 0px;
  color: #dfe2ff;
  margin-right: 46px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.logoimg{
  max-width: 75% !important;
}
.fa-bars{
  color: #5161ce;
}

.navbar-mainbg {
  background-color: #dfe2ff;
  padding: 0px;
}
#navbarSupportedContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
}
#navbarSupportedContent ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#navbarSupportedContent ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#navbarSupportedContent li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}
#navbarSupportedContent ul li a {
  color:  #5161ce;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  position: relative;
}
#navbarSupportedContent > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #5161ce;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.7s;
  font-weight: 800;
}
#navbarSupportedContent > ul > li > a.active {
  color: #5161ce;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.7s;
  font-weight: 800;
}
#navbarSupportedContent a:not(:only-child):after {
  content: "\f105";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 900;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#navbarSupportedContent .active > a:not(:only-child):after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.hori-selector {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.hori-selector .right,
.hori-selector .left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.hori-selector .right {
  right: -25px;
}
.hori-selector .left {
  left: -25px;
}
.hori-selector .right:before,
.hori-selector .left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #dfe2ff;
}
.hori-selector .right:before {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -25px;
}
.hori-selector .left:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: -25px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #navbarSupportedContent ul li a {
    padding: 12px 30px;
  }
  .hori-selector {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  }
  .hori-selector .left,
  .hori-selector .right {
    right: 10px;
  }
  .hori-selector .left {
    top: -25px;
    left: auto;
  }
  .hori-selector .right {
    bottom: -25px;
  }
  .hori-selector .left:before {
    left: -25px;
    top: -25px;
  }
  .hori-selector .right:before {
    bottom: -25px;
    left: -25px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 984px) {
  .navbar-logo {
    padding: 0px;
    color: #dfe2ff;
    margin-right: 46px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .logoimg{
    max-width: 75% !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav{
    margin-top: 15px !important;
  }
}
```

First, in this code, I have a navbar that has the Onclick event applied to it, so whenever I click on any navigation on the navbar, it is active, but I also want to add that when I scroll down my page, it will change my active nav-link, which is currently active.

Can anyone assist me in figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store section names in state and apply active styling to the current section only if it matches the name stored in state. Then using `onScroll` handler in the parent div, you can change the styling using setState.

```
const [activeState, setActiveState] = React.useState('about')
```

Then define a `onScroll` handler in the NavBar's parent div

```
onScroll={(event) => { 
        const val = event.currentTarget.scrollTop
        const maxVal = event.currentTarget.scrollHeight
        if(val >= maxVal / 5) setActiveState('services')
        else if(val >= 2 * (maxVal / 5)) setActiveState('career')
        else setActiveState('about')
     }}
```

I've only implemented for 3 sections but I'm sure you can manage the rest.

NOTE: This implementation assumes that each section is in the parent div and each section has 100% viewport height. I hope you get the intuition however since that's what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Can you change your setup a bit?
Right now you're using:
`<ul><li><Nav /></li></ul>`
can you change it to
`<ul><NavLink /></ul>`
This was you can merge styling in <li> and <a> in your `a.active` css class and you'll get  the desired result. NavLink from react-router-dom adds the `a.active` class on its own so I'd recommend it instead of Nav